# How do I get Tycho?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, plugins, tycho

Tycho is supposed to be a plug-in for maven for building eclipse plug-ins.

I have found various blogs and other articles about it, but the contained links to Tycho are all dead or not accessible for the general public, for example: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/04/tycho-040-roadmap/

The only thing I found is a project proposal on the eclipse site, but it doesn't reference any downloads: http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/tycho/

I found a svn repository, but it seems to be extremely dated:
http://svn.codehaus.org/m2eclipse/tycho/trunk/

So my question is: where do I get tycho from? Or is it dead and I should stop bothering?

I doubt it's dead, since I found out there is a talk about it on JAX2010 ...

Comment: This question no longer reflects the current state of the Tycho project.

Comment: This question was never intended to be a prophecy about the future.

Comment: This is fair enough - but how about updating it? E.g. you could remove the (partial) answers you found back then, and then the question would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tycho is not dead at all (it has indeed been submitted to become an Eclipse project) but is now  hosted (and actively developed) on github: http://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-tycho

More links from the **README.md**:

Tycho homepage http://tycho.sonatype.org/

Tycho wiki https://docs.sonatype.org/display/TYCHO/Index

Tycho bug tracking https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/TYCHO

Building Tycho from sources http://docs.sonatype.org/display/TYCHO/BuildingTycho

Answer (score 2):

Tycho works with stock Maven 3.x since at least Tycho-0.9.0 - it doesn't require a special distribution of Maven any more. (Adapted from http://twitter.com/jvanzyl/status/20700015111)

Comment: IOW, you just need to properly put tycho elements into your POM as needed. See, for instance, the EGit and JGit project trees at http://egit.eclipse.org/w/ for examples of usage in production.

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile, Tycho is hosted at Eclipse.org.

- [Official entry point for documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php)
- There are various indicators for the project's activity, e.g. a commit meter on the project's [status page](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=technology.tycho).
- You don't need to download Tycho manually - Maven will do that automatically for you (see also [the official download page](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/download.php)).